# Url Params in React with React Router

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Does anyone know how to get the URL params in React when using React Router?

I'm trying to do something like this:

```
filterList(key) {
   if (key===this.props.location.query){
    return Blogstore.state.blog
   }
```

to match with the unique key at the end of my link:

http://localhost:8080/blogshow/-KGYsxaXyMiej5cgU5A7

Answer (score 2):

The answer is:

```
this.props.routeParams.key
```